# How to find a sum 3 elements in array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sum, element

I have an array `A=[a1,a2,a3, ..., aN]` I would like to take a product of each 3 elements:

`s1=a1+a2+a3`

`s2=a4+a5+a6`

`...`

`sM=a(N-2)+a(N-1)+aN`

**My solution:**

```
k=size(A);
s=0;
for n=1:k
s(n)=s(n-2)+s(n-1)+s(n);
end
```

**Error:** Attempted to access s(2); index out of bounds because numel(s)=1.

Hoe to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to calculate `s`by using values from `s`. Dont you mean `s(n)=A(n-2)+A(n-1)+A(n);`? Also `size` returns more than one dimension on its own.

That being said, getting the 2 privous values `n-2` and `n-1` doenst work for n=1;2 (because you must have positive indices). You have to explain how the first two values should be handeled. I assume either 0 for elements not yet exisiting

```
k=size(A,2); %only the second dimension when A 1xn, or length(A) 
s=zeros(1,k); %get empty values instead of appending each value for better performance
s(1)=A(1);
s(2)=A(2)+A(1);
for n=3:k %start at 3 
    s(n)=A(n-2)+A(n-1)+A(n);
end
```

or `s`shoult be 2 values shorter than `A`.

```
k=size(A,2);
s=zeros(1,k-2);
for n=1:k-2
    s(n)=A(n)+A(n+1)+A(n+2); 
end
```

Comment: s(1) is a sum of a1, a2 and a3

Comment: The given array has N elements. I would like to compute a sum in one line

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sum in **blocks**, for the general case when the number of elements of `A` is **not necessarily a multiple** of the block size, you can use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
A = [3 8 5 8 2 3 4 7 9 6 4]; % 11 elements
s = 3; % block size
result = accumarray(ceil((1:numel(A))/s).', A(:));
```

If you want a **sliding** sum with a given block size, you can use [`conv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html):

```
A = [3 8 5 8 2 3 4 7 9 6 4]; % 11 elements
s = 3; % block size
result = conv(A(:).', ones(1,s), 'valid');
```

Comment: Since MATLAB R2016a, you can use the `movsum` function to calculated a sliding sum, which is a bit more intuitive than the convolution method.

Answer (score 1):

- You initialise `s` as a scalar with `s = 0`. Then you try and index it like an array, but it only has a single element.
- Your current logic (if fixed) will calculate this:

  ```
  s(1) = a(1)+a(2)+a(3) 
  s(2) = a(2)+a(3)+a(4)
  ... 
  % 's' will be 2 elements shorter than 'a'
  ```

  So we need to be a bit wiser with the indexing to get what you describe, which is

  ```
  s(1) = a(1)+a(2)+a(3) 
  s(2) = a(4)+a(5)+a(6)
  ... 
  % 's' will be a third as big as 'a'
  ```

You should pre-allocate `s` to the right size, like so:

```
k = numel(A); % Number of elements in 'A'
s = zeros( 1, k/3 ); % Output array, assuming 'k' is divisible by 3
for n = 0:3:k-3
    s(n/3+1) = a(n+1) + a(n+2) + a(n+3);
end
```

You could do this in one line by reshaping the array to have 3 rows, then summing down each column, this assumes that the number of elements in `a` is divisible by 3, and that `a` is a row vector...

```
s = sum( reshape( a, 3, [] ) );
```

Comment: For the last part, it is not actually required that `a` be a row vector, is it?

Comment: @LuisMendo I probably could have just said "vector" :)

Comment: @LuisMendo I am working with `a` as an N-dimensional array, a(1)... are M-dimensional array, `M<N`.

Comment: @Noel that's not mentioned at all in your question, and fundamentally affects how well the given answers will work... Please always include a representative [mcve] for what you want to achieve